# Is it possible to go back and create a Git/GitHub project's history retroactively...?

Tags: git, github

I've only dabbled in using GitHub (or Git at all) for the past 2 years.  But now I find myself wanting to create a GitHub repository and then, after the fact, somehow insert historical versions of the code into its history.  Is this at all possible?

The background is that I've got a C++ utility class that I've been sharing online for over 20 years.  Long before GitHub existed in the 1990s I posted it to sites like CodeGuru and CodeProject.  Never really moved it away.  But people still email me about it so I figured I should put it in GitHub and let them edit it.

But my "history" of this code is basically saved in an assortment of many static versions I have saved in one folder, by date.  I would prefer, if possible to post it there with the full history.   But doing that manually would take a while so if I could put the current version out there initially and then insert the history later that would be ideal.

I don't expect this is possible but figured I'd ask

Anyway can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git allows you to rebase things (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), that means that you are able to rewrite the history of your commits (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), you may even change the order of commits, but these operations MUST be done BEFORE you publish your project. Thus it seems not possible to achieve what you want, i.e. publish a bit of the history of your project, then adding older versions from time to time.

An alternative to the purely manual process : if all your versions are stored in a collection of folders, you may be able to write a script to build a git history from them. Basically, it would be something like:

1. define a working directory and initialize a git repo on it
2. loop over the folders, sorted by date (YYYYMMDD) for example

   2.1. empty your working dir except its .git subfolder

   2.2. copy the current folder content in the working dir and commit
3. publish your git project :)

Hope this helps...

Comment: I take this to mean: "No, but you can automate the manual process". Which I would agree is the best option.

Comment: You've got it :)

Comment: Looks like I've got some folder renaming to do.  But my own fault for not being very organized...

Comment: It should be possible too to automate the process of renaming the folders if you can access their creation date...

Comment: "these operations MUST be done BEFORE you publish your project" is simply not true; if you have permission to do so, you can make any changes you want to local commits (by rebasing, etc.) and then force push to update the state of the repo on GitHub.